# convertir array de objetos en un array de json en java con HashMap

Tags: java, json, hashmap

hola estoy intentando convertir el siguiente formato de array, en un array de json en java con HashMap  intente splitear pero la descripción llega con una coma, dentro de la descripción.

```
 [
    {idpersona=1123,
    numeroCorreccion=1, 
    fecha=18/02/2014,  
    descripcion= descripcion del tramite, de la persona,
    estado = true
    },
    {idpersona=1124,
    numeroCorreccion=4, 
    fecha=18/02/2015,  
    descripcion= descripcion del tramite, de la persona2,
    estado = true
    }
]

**tendría que quedar así:**

 [
    {"idpersona":"1123",
    "numeroCorreccion":"1", 
    "fecha":"18/02/2014",  
    "descripcion":"descripcion del tramite, de la persona",
    "estado": "true"
    },
    {"idpersona":"1124",
    "numeroCorreccion":"4", 
    "fecha":"18/02/2015",  
    "descripcion": "descripcion del tramite, de la persona2",
    "estado": "true"
    }
]
```

Comment: ¿No podrías hacer split por fin de línea en lugar de por la coma? Y esas cadenas de texto... ¿como es que no están delimitadas por comillas? ¿De dónde estás sacando esos datos?